# How to wait an HTTP request before atttempting to reconnect in Socket.IO (with RxJS)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, rxjs

I'm using Socket.IO client and have the following code:

```
export const notificationsWsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Socket | null>(null)

signedInObservable.pipe(
    switchMap(user => forkJoin([of(user), from(getNotificationsWebsocketTicket())]))
).subscribe(values => {
    notificationsWsSubject.next(
        io(SERVER_URL, {
            auth: {
                ticket: values[1].data,
                accessToken: values[0].accessToken
            }
        })
    )
})
```

basically whenever a user signs in (`signedInObservable`) I request a ticket from my server (`getNotificationsWebsocketTicket()`) and only then I actually open a websocket connection.

Now I want to do the same for when a connection has closed for some reason (temporary offline) and a reconnnect attempt has been made by Socket.IO.

How can I make sure Socket.IO attempts to "reconnect" **only** after I made a request to
`getNotificationsWebsocketTicket()`? so that I can reconnect again with `auth` data?

something like:

```
io.beforeReconnect(() => {
  return getNotificationsWebsocketTicket()
}).then(ticket => io(SERVER_URL, { 
    auth: { 
        ticket: ticket
        accessToken: getToken()
    })
)
```

Comment: How do you know it has disconnected?

Comment: I listen to the ```disconnect``` event: ```socket.on("disconnect", () => { })```

Comment: You can use [fromEvent](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEvent) to subscribe to the disconnect event.
I'm unsure whether you want to call `io` each time something happens. What happens to the previous `io` object? Does that affect performance by opening/closing connections?